# Docker network host commands for remote access

Tags: docker, dockerfile, kali-linux

I'm trying to build a linux docker container with xrdp service installed so that I can remotely access the RDP service over not only the localhost interface but also the host network eth0 ip interface.  I'm failing at understanding what I'm missing here with docker networking and properly launching the container.  Docker running on Ubuntu Linux 20.04.  As a test, when I run this docker command:

`docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx`

I observer that nginx is listening on port 80 and exposed on the localhost interface and I can access it with a browser.  Verifying with:

`sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 80`

Now here is the linux container I'm trying to build and launch.  I use a Dockerfile to launch an xrdp service.

```
FROM kalilinux/kali-rolling

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade && apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get install -y wget && apt-get clean

RUN apt-get -y install vim net-tools whois netcat exploitdb man-db dirb nikto wpscan uniscan nodejs npm python3-pip tor proxychains

RUN apt-get install xrdp lxde-core lxde tigervnc-standalone-server -y

COPY ./xrdp.ini /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

COPY ./Xwrapper.config /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config

RUN service xrdp start

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Now I build the container and try to run it like this:

`docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_kali kali`

The container doesn't look like it runs and there is not a port 3389 listening on lo or eth0 interfaces.  Now when I run the container another way, I can access the host with an RDP client over the Docker0 IP interface (172.17.0.2):

`docker run -ti kali`

But this only exposes the RDP service over Docker0 private network.  The goal or use case is to build a container that can be accessed over eth0 interface of the host computer.  The user can RDP into it and use the GUI to run tools.  Any help appreciated on what I'm missing here.

Comment: Generally a Docker container needs to run the single server process it's running as its foreground process; since an image doesn't persist running processes, `RUN service ... start` doesn't do anything.  If you replace the `ENTRYPOINT` with a `CMD` that starts the server in the foreground you should be able to connect to it using the normal `docker run -p` option.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I tried to implement but still missing something here.  I tried `CMD ["service xrdp start"]` and then `docker run -p 3389:3389` but I'm getting an error of, "OCI runtime create failed" and "executable file not found in $PATH".  I will keep on doing some research, reading, and testing of this.

Comment: To a first approximation, you should assume commands like `service` don't work in Docker.  Launch the server _directly_, as a foreground process, not via an init script or wrapper.

Comment: Finally got it.  Running with default was automatically demonizing service into background.  Found special flag of -n that made it go the foreground.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the resolution in Dockerfile:
`CMD /usr/sbin/xrdp-sesman;/usr/sbin/xrdp -n`

Then launched the image with -p:
`docker run -d --name kali-image -p 3389:3389 kali`

Verify port is listening:
`docker port kali-image`

Thanks to David Maze above.